# What is the equivalent of on.(child_added) on firesore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting started with firestore here :)

I want to receive an event every time a document updates or is created inside a collection. 
I want to receive only 1 document .. the one updated / created / deleted .. etc. I don't want to get the hole collection for each change.

Similar to how `.on("child_added")` worked in real time database.

For example:

```
// logs the entire collection.
db.collection("categories").onShapshot(snap => console.log(snap));
```

Gives me the hole list of categories again.. instead of just getting the document that was created.

I want to use this to update/remove/create that document in the dom in real time.

I don't see how to do this based on [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

**Is this super important and basic feature intentionally not supported anymore?**

Or is just me not seeing something obvious..
Notice i don't have anything specific to query on.

I just want to get the specific category back once it get's created. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When there is a change in the data for your query, you get called with the entire new data set for that query in a `QuerySnapshot`. But in that snapshot is the information on what has changed. If you only want to do something with the newly added documents, check whether the document was added with this [sample from the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots):

> ```
> db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
>     .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
>         snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
>             if (change.type === "added") {
>                 console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
>                 // This is equivalent to child_added
>             }
>             if (change.type === "modified") {
>                 console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
>                 // This is equivalent to child_changed
>             }
>             if (change.type === "removed") {
>                 console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
>                 // This is equivalent to child_removed
>             }
>         });
>     });
> ```

Note that the unmodified data for this listener is read from the local cache, so won't have to be re-read from the server.

Comment: thanks for reply :) i've read that. in my case i have nothing to filter against. Can i live it as `.where().onSnapshot`? Why is it assumed i want to query it? Am I in some sort  of anti-pattern usage?

Comment: You don't need to query. The `change.type` is available in any `onSnapshot`, including yours.